# Editing HOSTS file for specific URL?

Tags: windows, hosts

I have tried to edit my HOSTS file to block just a specific url like so:

```
127.0.0.1 google.com/pagetoblock
127.0.0.1 www.google.com/pagetoblock
```

However that isn't working.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your HOSTS file only allows you to set the IP address for (as the name suggests) the host (e.g. google.com or www.google.com). You cannot set the IP address for specific pages.

You could use a tool like Microsoft Fiddler to set the IP Address for specific URLs, but this would require Fiddler be running continuously.

Fiddler has a rules engine accessed by **Rules** → **Customize Rules**.
There is a great set of [samples](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/dev/scriptsamples.asp) for your learning, but the following script should work.

For example, to block the logo on the http://www.google.co.uk homepage, you could use the following script:

```
if (oSession.url == "www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo3w.png"){
    // Prevent this request from going through an upstream proxy
    oSession.bypassGateway = true; 
    // Rewrite the IP address of target server
    oSession["x-overrideHost"] = "127.0.0.1";  
    // Set the color of the request in RED in Fiddler, for easy tracing
    oSession["ui-color"]="red"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, how could I do this?

Comment: @user1294381 I've added a sample rule to my answer.

Comment: Have you tried this? I've tried it and I still can't get it to work. I'm fairly well versed with JS and I'm very certain I've put it under the right condition.

Comment: I've added a tested solution now. Please confirm you are adding this code to the `OnBeforeRequest` method, and that you are definitely using the correct URL, with no `http` prefix...?