# Windows HOST file - redirect directory only

Tags: windows, redirect, host

For personal uses, I need to redirect a remote directory on a website to a local directory. I'm nearly sure I have to put this stuff into the windows Host file.
I'd like to do something like:

```
#Local remote
mywebsite.com/directory localhost/directory
```

But I'd like to keep access to `mywebsite.com/whatever` where `whatever` is different of `directory`.

Is there a way to do that or do I need to use a browser plugin ?

Thanks.

Comment: You definitely can't do it with `hosts` file.

Comment: What webserver are you using on your `localhost`?

Comment: This is not a programming question. It is better-suited to SuperUser. It is also an exact duplicate of [Editing HOSTS file for specific URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987245/editing-hosts-file-for-specific-url).

Comment: Depends, I'm now planning to do it programmatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hosts file will only allow you to set IP addresses for certain host names. It will not help you here. Browser plugin seems overkill here, but it's possible. You could try to find a HTTP proxy that allows you to change the requests the way you want to.

In any case this will require some external application/plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would I do that with an external application ? I don't think it's possible to "manipulate" the source code of a page outside the browser !

Comment: You get a HTTP proxy and set your browser to use it. The proxy can then manipulate the requests and redirect then wherever you want it to. I can't give links to any proxies that do this since I haven't needed this kind of functionality and I'm not sure if they exist. But it would be the best solution since it would manipulate the actual requests from any browser/application that can use a proxy.

Answer (score 3):

The hosts file is only used to translate host names to IP addresses. You cannot block/redirect any custom URL that way.

if you are searching for external application for that , i think **Fiddler** is what you need : http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/dev/scriptsamples.asp